# How to integrate two php json file into one [autocomplete]?

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

I have two json files and i want to merge two JSON files into one.

**Php**

```
<input type="text" name="image" />
<input type="text" name="file" />
```

**Javascript for first input**

```
$('input[name=\'image\']').autocomplete({ 
      minLength: 2,
      source: function( request, response ) {
            $.getJSON( "files/", {
                term: extractLast( request.term )
                }, response );
                },
       create: function () {
            $(this).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
               return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append('<a><img src="files/' + item.label + '.jpg' />
                     ' + item.label + '</c></a>')
            .appendTo( ul );
                  };
            },

});
```

**Javascript for second input**

```
$('input[name=\'file\']').autocomplete({ 
      minLength: 2,
      source: function( request, response ) {
            $.getJSON( "files/", {
                term: extractLast( request.term )
                }, response );
                },
        create: function () {
            $(this).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
               return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append('<a>' + item.label + '</c></a>')
            .appendTo( ul );
                  };
            },

});
```

**json for first input**

```
if (empty($_GET['term'])) exit ; 
   $q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);
   if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $q = stripslashes($q);
      $files = array(); 
   foreach(glob('image/*.jpg*', GLOB_BRACE) as $key=>$file) { 
     $files[] = substr($file, 0, -4); }
      $files = array_unique($files); 
    $files = array_combine($files, $files);
      $result = array(); 
foreach ($files as $key=>$value) { 
    if (strpos(strtolower($key), $q) !== false) { 
        array_push($result, 
        array("id"=>$value, "label"=>$key, 
            "value" => strip_tags($key))); }
      if (count($result) > 11) break; } 
 echo json_encode($result);
```

**json for Second input**

```
if (empty($_GET['term'])) exit ; 
   $q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);
   if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $q = stripslashes($q);
      $files = array(); 
   foreach(glob('image/*.txt*', GLOB_BRACE) as $key=>$file) { 
     $files[] = substr($file, 0, -4); }
      $files = array_unique($files); 
    $files = array_combine($files, $files);
      $result = array(); 
foreach ($files as $key=>$value) { 
    if (strpos(strtolower($key), $q) !== false) { 
        array_push($result, 
        array("id"=>$value, "label"=>$key, 
            "value" => strip_tags($key))); }
      if (count($result) > 11) break; } 
 echo json_encode($result);
```

How to mearge all into one? There has a problem with json beacause first input only show image files name with preview and second one only show text files name then how to integrate json files into one?

Comment: Decode them both to PHP arrays then do your merging and then encode them back to JSON.

Comment: How? I don't understand, please give a code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres the solution:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="image" />
<input type="text" name="file" />
```

Javascript:

```
function split( val ) {
    return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}
function extractLast( term ) {
    return split( term ).pop();
}
$("input[name='image'], input[name='file']").autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function(request, response) {
        var thisType = this.element[0].name;
        $.getJSON("/test", {
            term: extractLast(request.term),
            type: thisType
        }, response );
    }
}).autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    var thisType = this.element[0].name;
    if (thisType == 'image') {
        return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append('<a><img src="files/' + item.label + '.jpg" />' + item.label + '</a>')
            .appendTo( ul );
    } else {
        return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append('<a>' + item.label + '</a>')
            .appendTo( ul );
    }
};
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if (empty($_GET['term'])) exit;

$q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);

$type = strtolower($_GET["type"]);

if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $q = stripslashes($q);

$files = array();

if ($type == 'image') {
    foreach(glob('image/*.jpg*', GLOB_BRACE) as $key=>$file) {
        $files[] = substr($file, 0, -4);
    }
} else {
    foreach(glob('image/*.txt*', GLOB_BRACE) as $key=>$file) {
        $files[] = substr($file, 0, -4);
    }
}

$files = array_unique($files);
$files = array_combine($files, $files);

$result = array();
foreach ($files as $key=>$value) {
    if (strpos(strtolower($key), $q) !== false) {
        array_push($result, array("id"=>$value, "label"=>$key, "value" => strip_tags($key)));
    }
    if (count($result) > 11) break;
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Ill put this through a test and let you know

Comment: ok but can you explain when i add `$type = strtolower($_GET["type"]);` and `if ($type == 'image') {` then autocomplete stop working.

Comment: what libraries / extensions are you using, I gathered your using jQuery and possibly jQuery UI for autocomplete.

Comment: Thank you for reply bro i have small personal music site i am using jquery ui as same duplicate of http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote and i want to when my friend type on first input search result need to show image files name with preview and when type on 2nd input then results need to show txt [lyrics text] files name but how to do this?

Comment: Closer but first input showing only text files name not jpg.. @Danny

Comment: Tested and working, updated the javascript to how you need it

Comment: Thank you for trying to helping me. but still not working only show me text files.. :)

Comment: I have got this working, check over PHP and javascript that they are the same, my example is at http://www.dannybroadbent.com/test/

Comment: on my example you can use the word "hello" on the example