# How to mearge two json files?

Tags: php, json

**Related question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029040/how-to-integrate-two-php-json-file-into-one-autocomplete)**

**First json :**

```
   if (empty($_GET['term'])) exit ; 
       $q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);
       if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $q = stripslashes($q);
          $files = array(); 
       foreach(glob('image/*.jpg*', GLOB_BRACE) as $key=>$file) { 
         $files[] = substr($file, 0, -4); }
          $files = array_unique($files); 
        $files = array_combine($files, $files);
          $result = array(); 
    foreach ($files as $key=>$value) { 
        if (strpos(strtolower($key), $q) !== false) { 
            array_push($result, 
            array("id"=>$value, "label"=>$key, 
                "value" => strip_tags($key))); }
          if (count($result) > 11) break; } 
     echo json_encode($result);
```

**Second json :**

```
if (empty($_GET['term'])) exit ; 
   $q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);
   if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $q = stripslashes($q);
      $files = array(); 
   foreach(glob('image/*.txt*', GLOB_BRACE) as $key=>$file) { 
     $files[] = substr($file, 0, -4); }
      $files = array_unique($files); 
    $files = array_combine($files, $files);
      $result = array(); 
foreach ($files as $key=>$value) { 
    if (strpos(strtolower($key), $q) !== false) { 
        array_push($result, 
        array("id"=>$value, "label"=>$key, 
            "value" => strip_tags($key))); }
      if (count($result) > 11) break; } 
 echo json_encode($result);
```

How to mearge all into one? I have 2 input fields and with json first input only show image files name with preview and second one only show text files name then how to integrate json files into one?

Comment: you don't have "php json" files. there's no such thing. you have two php scripts that OUTPUT json... if you want to merge them, then combine the common code and add loops or whatever else is necessary for the "unique" stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing your two files, this should be what you looking to do (providing you are wanting to run just the one file to output the JSON response).

```
<?php
if (empty($_GET['term'])) exit;

$q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);

if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $q = stripslashes($q);

$files = array();

foreach(glob('image/*.jpg*', GLOB_BRACE) as $key=>$file) {
    $files[] = substr($file, 0, -4);
}
foreach(glob('image/*.txt*', GLOB_BRACE) as $key=>$file) {
    $files[] = substr($file, 0, -4);
}

$files = array_unique($files);
$files = array_combine($files, $files);

$result = array();

foreach ($files as $key=>$value) {
    if (strpos(strtolower($key), $q) !== false) {
        array_push($result, array("id"=>$value, "label"=>$key, "value" => strip_tags($key)));
    }
    if (count($result) > 11) break;
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Second solution based on your comment:

```
<?php
if (empty($_GET['term']) || empty($_GET['term2'])) exit;

$q = strtolower($_GET["term"]);
$q2 = strtolower($_GET["term2"]);

if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $q = stripslashes($q);

$files = array();
$files2 = array();

foreach(glob('image/*.jpg*', GLOB_BRACE) as $key=>$file) {
    $files[] = substr($file, 0, -4);
}
foreach(glob('image/*.txt*', GLOB_BRACE) as $key=>$file) {
    $files2[] = substr($file, 0, -4);
}

$files = array_unique($files);
$files = array_combine($files, $files);
$files2 = array_unique($files2);
$files2 = array_combine($files2, $files2);

$result = array();
foreach ($files as $key=>$value) {
    if (strpos(strtolower($key), $q) !== false) {
        array_push($result, array("id"=>$value, "label"=>$key, "value" => strip_tags($key)));
    }
    if (count($result) > 11) break;
}
foreach ($files2 as $key=>$value) {
    if (strpos(strtolower($key), $q2) !== false) {
        array_push($result, array("id"=>$value, "label"=>$key, "value" => strip_tags($key)));
    }
    if (count($result) > 11) break;
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Actually i have 2 inputs and There has a problem with json beacause first input only show image files name with preview and second one only show text files name then how to integrate json files into one? @Danny

Comment: Please see second solution to see if this suits you

Comment: please see reference here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029040/how-to-integrate-two-php-json-file-into-one-autocomplete

Comment: you see? is possible to show different value for 2 inputs from same source?

Comment: Take a look at answer posted on your link you shared above

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have valid data at the end of your code snippets, I would convert them to arrays, merge them, then re-encode to json.

```
$json1 = '{"title" : [{"some data":"some more data"}]}';
$json2 = '{"title2" : [{"some data2":"some more data2"}]}';

$complete = array_merge(JSON_decode($json1, true), JSON_decode($json2, true));

$newJson = JSON_encode($complete);
```

[heres a fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/eb3r-md2y)

Comment: Can you edit your code as my example? please........

Comment: You create 2 arrays anyway at the end of each snippet, just merge them first before encoding to JSON

Comment: Actually i have 2 inputs and There has a problem with json beacause first input only show image files name with preview and second one only show text files name then how to integrate json files into one? @Matt HB

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to change the 2 scripts above you can do something like this:

```
<?php

$script1_path = 'http://path/to/your/first/script.php';
$script2_path = 'http://path/to/your/second/script.php';

$json1 = file_get_contents($script1_path.'?term=hello');
$result1 = json_decode($json1);

$json2 = file_get_contents($script2_path.'?term=world');
$result2 = json_decode($json2);

$merged_result = array_merge($result1, $result2);
echo json_encode($merged_result);

?>
```

Warning: depending on the configuration of your server, file_get_content server may not be allowed to load http content.

Otherwise the best solution might be to change your architecture to generate your 2 arrays in one php file :

```
$q1 = strtolower($_GET["term1"]);
...
$q2 = strtolower($_GET["term2"]);
...
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: And if the search term is the same in the 2 files, you should use the solution of @Danny Broadbent.

Comment: Actually i have 2 inputs and There has a problem with json beacause first input only show image files name with preview and second one only show text files name then how to integrate json files into one? @jonas

Comment: please see reference here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029040/how-to-integrate-two-php-json-file-into-one-autocomplete

Comment: If you search image files with a name and text files with an other name, my first proposal is the quick and dirty way (updated)

Comment: Why do you  want to merge the 2 jsons ?

Comment: Need so. can you do this?

Comment: is possible to show different value for 2 inputs from same source?